# How to represent a derivative of a function that has more than 2 vector valued inputs

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I've been going through the theory behind deep learning which required me to learn some vector calculus and it occurred to me how one would find the derivative of a function with respect to a function that has more than 2 vector valued inputs?

For a function with that has a 1 vector valued input $f(\mathbf{x})$ we could simply take the derivative with respect to each element of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ resulting in the gradient vector:

$$\nabla f_{\mathbf{x}} = \begin{bmatrix} 
                           \frac{\delta f(\mathbf{x})}{\delta x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\delta f(\mathbf{x})}{\delta x_n}\end{bmatrix}$$

For a function with that has a 2 vector valued input $g(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ I could take find the gradient vector with respect to $g$ for $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ then take the outer product (if my understanding is correct, please correct me if I'm wrong) resulting in:
$$(\nabla g_{\mathbf{x}})^T(\nabla g_{\mathbf{y}})$$
(I don't know what symbol the outer product is represented by). But the result of this should be a `n x m` dimensional matrix where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{R}^{n} $ and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbf{R}^m$.

So if the above is correct how would one generalize this to a vector valued function of `k` input vectors?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a function with domain $\mathbb {R}^n \times \mathbb {R}^m$ but this is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n+m}$ so you can think of a function with two vector arguments as a function of one argument with more components. The isomorphism is $((x_1,...,x_n),(y_1,...,y_m))\mapsto (x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m)$

The extension to the case of $k$ vector arguments is achieved by the same process of 'removing the brackets'.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example?

Comment: If $\mathrm {x}=(x_1,x_2)$ and $\mathrm {y}=(y_1,y_2)$ then let $f(x,y)=\mathrm {x}+\mathrm {y}= (x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2)=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)$ but this is effectively the same as the function of four real numbers $g(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=(z_1+z_2,z_3+z_4)$